# php image upload and display in a same div

Tags: php

I want to upload a image to a directory and I want to display it on the same time in a div. This is a part of my html page.

```
<body>
  <div id="imgspace1" class="container">
  <form action="php/imgUpload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="Submit">
  </form>
  </div>
```

and this is my php page

```
<?php
// set the upload location
$imgUpload = "../uploads/";

// if the form has been submitted then save and display the image(s)
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    // loop through the uploaded file
    foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value){
        $image_tmp = $value['tmp_name'];
        $image = $value['name'];
        $image_file = "{$imgUpload}{$image}";
        // move the file to the permanent location
        if(move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,$image_file)){
            echo <<<HEREDOC
<div style="float:left;margin-right:10px">
    <img src="{$image_file}" alt="file not found" /></br>
</div>
HEREDOC;
        }
        else{
            echo "<h1>image file upload failed, image too big after compression</h1>";           
        }
    }
}
else{
    ?>

<?php
}
?>
```

but the image display in another page. So how can I display uploaded image in that "imgspace1" div?

Comment: Use PLUpload image/file uploader. It uploads file in backend and you can use path to display

Comment: And are you using AJAX to post the form or are you using a simple HTTP Post Request?

Comment: On the other page where you can see the image are you using an external URL? ex: http://yoursite/uploads/image.png ?

Comment: Thank you  Chintan7027. I'll try that.

Comment: I think its better if I use ajax, right Jacques Koekemoer ?

Comment: no  ksealey. image loading on my php page

Answer (score 0):

This example demonstrate the solution of your problem

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="//jsfiddle.net/chintan7027/s8nvgnsn/2/embedded/" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```